# Can I change constant from int to byte in Java without breaking backward compatibility?

Tags: java, casting, backwards-compatibility, primitive-types

I am submitting a [change](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/1050/files) to [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) which has in previous releases defined a set of constants as `int` type, specifically:

```
int VER_EQUAL = 1;
int VER_GREATER = 2;
int VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
... etc...
```

(Since they are defined in an `interface` they are automatically `static` and `final`.)

These constants are used as the `Condition` argument in the [VerSetConditionMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/nf-winnt-versetconditionmask) function, which requires a `BYTE` argument, mapped in JNA to Java's `byte`.

To use the existing `int` constants in that function would require me (and other users) to explicitly typecast them, so I want to change these constant values in the library to be `byte`, e.g.,

```
byte VER_EQUAL = 1;
byte VER_GREATER = 2;
byte VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
... etc...
```

I do not think this change breaks backwards compatibility, because any code using these constants must currently expect at least an `int`, and will happily widen the `byte` without complaint.  I've written plenty of test code to convince myself of this.  I'm aware that changing `Object` types (like `Integer` to `Byte`) would not work, but I believe this is fine for primitives.  However, despite an hour searching the web for confirmation, I remain the tiniest bit unconvinced.

Is this change backwards compatible? Or am I wrong and is there a case where this could break existing code relying on the `int` primitive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it's obvious. But maybe not. If some third party user fetched the `int` values and stored them locally in `Integer` objects, changing the `int` to `byte` will cause a compile time error there:

```
interface IntToByteWithInt
{
    int VER_EQUAL = 1;
    int VER_GREATER = 2;
    int VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
}

interface IntToByteWithByte
{
    byte VER_EQUAL = 1;
    byte VER_GREATER = 2;
    byte VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
}

public class IntToByte
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer a = IntToByteWithInt.VER_EQUAL;

        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to Integer  
        Integer b = IntToByteWithByte.VER_EQUAL;
    }
}
```

---

Beyond that, I think that one should at least mention *reflection* for completeness.

I also considered the ternary operator (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2 ) as a hot candidate, but did not manage to cause an error with that one.

Comment: Gah. I guess autoboxing should have been obvious.  Another probably more common manifestation of your example would be a method that takes an Integer argument: if  `void foo(Integer bar) { ... }` was defined, then `int i; foo(i);` works while `byte b; foo(b);` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this change backwards compatible?

No.

Even though constants are normally inlined, the field is still a part of the class file, so it is possible that some dynamic lookup references the field using it's old type which is `int`. For instance:

```
// defined in `MyClass`
static final byte x = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    lookup().findStaticGetter(MyClass.class, "x", int.class); // old code
}
```

This throws a `NoSuchFieldException` since the lookup is looking for the old type of the field.

This also goes for byte code writing APIs that access the field, e.g. with [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/):

```
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
cw.visit(55, ACC_PUBLIC, "Test", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_STATIC, "m", "()V", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "MyClass", "x", "I"); // looking for int field
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(I)V", false);
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(-1, -1);
mv.visitEnd();

Class<?> cls = lookup().defineClass(cw.toByteArray());
cls.getMethod("m").invoke(null); // NoSuchFieldError
```

The above code works and prints `10` if the field is of type `int`, but fails once it is changed to `byte`.